# Integrate ImageMagick & MagickWand with php ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have installed both ImageMagick and MagickWand in my ubuntu system by refering to the detailed instructions provided in [Install ImageMagick From Source](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) and [MagickWand For PHP](http://www.magickwand.org/). When I chack whether ImageMagick is installed or not by command identify -version, it shows me follwing message

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-9 Q16 i686 2013-12-09 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png tiff x xml zlib
```

That means Image Magick is installed. And When I check the version of MagickWand with `MagickWand-config --version` it also shows me the version number `6.8.7 Q16`.

But problem is when I try to intialize the wrapper class of the MagickWand i.e. `$magick_wand=NewMagickWand();` It shows me the Fatal Error as follows,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function NewMagickWand()
```

Can somebody tell me where did I make a mistake and how to make it work with php.

Comment: have you http://www.magickwand.org/

Comment: Yes already tried that, but i think I missed the exact steps to configure. I have also placed the magickwand folder inside /usr/include/php5/ext and added the magickwand.so to php.ini. But still failed and exhausted.

Comment: try one more time if you are not sure if installation process.